# deviseのログイン時に、ユーザ名、メールアドレス、パスワードでログインしたい

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

現在Railsアプリを作成の中で、Devise Gemを使用しています。
デフォルトではログイン時に、メールアドレスとパスワードでログイン出来るかと思います。
そこにユーザ名も追加したいと思い、調べていると大体の記事が、
**ユーザ名とパスワード**又は**メールアドレスとパスワード**のログイン方法についてしか説明されていませんでした。
出来れば**ユーザ名とメールアドレスとパスワード**の3つでログイン機能を実装したいと考えています。
何かご教授頂ければ幸いです。

[実行した事]
config/initializers/devise.rb に
`config.authentication_keys = [:username]`を追加すれば、
ユーザ名とパスワードでログインできたので、
`config.authentication_keys = [:email]`も追加したら、
メールアドレスとパスワードだけでログイン出来てしまう。

[app/controllers/application_controller.rb]

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    added_attrs = [:email, :username, :password, :password_confirmation]
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit :sign_up, keys: added_attrs
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit :account_update, keys: added_attrs
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit :sign_in, keys: added_attrs
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2度代入すると後から代入した方だけ有効になると思います。

authentication_key**s** と複数形になっているので、

```
config.authentication_keys = [:username, :email]
```

のように配列で両方同時に指定すれば良いのではないでしょうか。

devise の実装をみてこう設定できそうと確認しただけで、実際に試したわけではないので、違っていたらすいません。

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-sign-in-using-their-username-or-email-address
この記事を参考にしてみてはいかがでしょうか。`login`という仮想の属性を定義するのがポイントのようです。